# passphraseless access to rsync with ssh through cron fails

Tags: ssh, cron, rsync

I have setup ssh  keys without a passphrase (Ubuntu) and copied them to my remote server (Centos6). I can login with ssh without a password successfully under my username.

When I execute the following script in a terminal under my username  (not root) it works. When I execute it through cron under my user name it fails with response:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
```

Here is  the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=/home/<username>/git/kodi-playercorefactory/bash-scripts:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
rsync -rvzO  -e 'ssh -p 6135 -i /home/<username>/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' <username>@xx.xxx.xx.xx:<filename> <filename>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Does ssh without using cron work?

Comment: Just in case this isn't properly passphraseless (eg using `ssh-agent`) you can test from the command line with `env -i ./yourscript.sh` so that it runs in a clean environment.   If that works properly then you should test under cron with `ssh -vv` to get more debugging output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-i` option of `ssh` is supposed to input the file name that contains the private key, not public key. But you have presumably given the file name containing the public key, given by the name `/home/<username>/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.

Assuming the private key is in `/home/<username>/.ssh/id_rsa`, the following should work:

```
rsync -rvzO  -e 'ssh -p 6135 -i /home/<username>/.ssh/id_rsa' <username>@xx.xxx.xx.xx:<filename> <filename>
```

Comment: If the script really is running as user `<username>` then the whole `-i /home/<username>/.ssh/id_rsa` bit is irrelevant anyway.

Comment: Thank you heemayl, using the private key did  the trick.